# Разработка галереи с хранением добавленных фотографий на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

В приложении WPF для курсового проекта понадобилась реализация подобия галереи, где пользователь добавляет фото и может их просматривать в приложении и соответственно удалить ненужное. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Желательно на примере

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Разбейте его на составляющие, попробуйте реализовать их сами и потом, если по конкретному аспекту у вас что-то не получается, приходите, задавайте, поможем. Ну а сейчас, ну вы сами подумайте, вы пишете курсовую, то есть то, что покажет ваш навык, то, что показывает чему вы научились, но просите реализовать за вас весь проект, ибо ведь "галерея", это не просто "привязать картинки к коллекции", это если делать по уму, то тут и надо их хранить где либо (база?), и надо реализовывать механизмы добавления/удаления, и вывод на экран (слайдер может быть?), короче куча всего.

Comment: Самый простой вариант: делаете `ListBox`, `Image`, две кнопки (добавить/удалить) и поле для ввода пути до картинки. Ну а дальше все привязываете, по клику "Добавить", путь записывается в привязанную к `ListBox` коллекцию, а при клике на объект в `ListBox` картинка отображаются в `Image`, ну и при клике "Удалить", значение удаляется из привязанной коллекции. Вот вам самая простая реализация, которую даже особо и галереей назвать нельзя, чисто вывод картинок. Ну и что, хотите сказать, что вы не сможете подобное реализовать?